# ReactsStars Rating with Redux are not allowing to set state

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am getting the following error:

> bundle.js:74359 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined.

I have sent `onChange` method with bind and also with the Arrow rocket but no success.

```
import ReactStars from 'react-stars'
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm, initialize, change} from 'redux-form'; 
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class RatingsNew extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { overall_review : 1 };
  }

  renderField(field){

    const {meta:{touched, error}} = field;
    if (field.type =="text"){
     return(
      <div className = "form-group">
        <label>{field.label}</label>

        <input
          className = "form-control"
          {...field.input}
        />

        <div className = "text-help">
          {touched ? error : "" }
        </div>  
      </div>  
    );
    }
    else{



    return(

      <div className = "form-group">
        <label>{field.label}</label>


        <ReactStars
          count = {5}
          size = {20}
          onChange={(value)=>{
            onChange(field.input.name, value)
          }}

        />



        <div className = "text-help">
          {touched ? error : "" }
        </div>  
      </div>  
    );
    }
  }

  onSubmit(values){
    console.log(values)
  }

  render(){

     const  {handleSubmit} = this.props
        return(

      <form  onSubmit= {handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
        <div className= "row">
        <div className= "col-md-4">
        <Field 
          label = "Student Name"
          name = "student_name" 
          type = "text"
          component = {this.renderField}
        />
        </div>
        <div className= "col-md-4">
        <Field
          label = "Email"
          name =  "student_email"
          type = "text"
          component = {this.renderField}
        />
        </div>
        <div className= "col-md-4">
        <Field 
          label = "Anonymous"
          name  = "anonymous"
          type = "text"
          component = {this.renderField}
        />
        </div>
        </div>

        <Field 
          label = "Title"
          name  = "title"
          type = "text"
          component = {this.renderField}
        />
        <Field 
          label = "Description"
          name  = "description"
          type = "text"
          component = {this.renderField}
        />
        <div className = "row">
        <div className = "col-sm-3">
        <Field 
          label = "Overall"
          name  = "overall_review"
          type = "hidden"
          component = {this.renderField}
        />
        </div>
        <div className = "col-sm-3">
        <Field 
          label = "Curriculum"
          name  = "curriculum_review"
          type = "hidden"
          component = {this.renderField}
        />
        </div>
        <div className = "col-sm-3">
        <Field 
          label = "Instructor"
          name  = "instructor_review"
          type = "hidden"
          component = {this.renderField}
        />
        </div>
        <div className = "col-sm-3">
        <Field 
          label = "Job Assistance"
          name  = "job_assistance_review"
          type = "hidden"
          component = {this.renderField}
        />
        </div>
        </div>
        <button type = "submit" className = "btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>

    );
    };
}
function validate(values){
  const errors = {}
  if(!values.student_name){
    errors.student_name = "Enter the Name"
  }
  if(!values.student_email){
    errors.student_email = "Enter the Email"
  }
  if(!values.title){
    errors.title = "Enter the Title"
  }
  if(!values.description){
    errors.description = "Enter the Description"
  }
  if(!values.overall_review){
    errors.overall_review = "Share Overall Review"
  }
  if(!values.curriculum_review){
    errors.curriculum_review = "Share Curriculum Review"
  }
  if(!values.curriculum_review){
    errors.instructor_review = "Share Instructor Review"
  }
  if(!values.job_assistance_review){
    errors.job_assistance_review = "Share Job Assistance Review"
  }
  return errors
}

function onChange(name, value){
  console.log(value);
  console.log(name);
  this.setState("rating": value);  
}

export default reduxForm({
validate,
form: 'RatingForm'
})(
connect(null,{change})(RatingsNew)
);
```

What do I need to do to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onChange` function should be part of the component so you can use `this` properly :

```
class RatingsNew extends Component {

  // .. other code ..

  onChangeRating = (name, value) => {
    console.log(value);
    console.log(name);
    this.setState({
      rating: value
    }); 
  }

  // also bind `renderField`:
  renderField = (field) => {
    // ...
  }
}
```

---

```
<ReactStars
  count={5}
  size={20}
  onChange={(value) => {
    this.onChangeRating(field.input.name, value);
  }}
/>
```

Comment: after implementing your soultion have error ...  bundle.js:74267 Uncaught TypeError: _this2.onChangeRating is not a function

Comment: it looks like you might need to bind `renderField` as well:  `renderField = (field) => {`.

Comment: #AustinGreco now I can access the function but get the following error Uncaught Error: setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables.

Comment: I see.. your `setState` needs to pass an object, I updated the answer

Comment: #AustinGreco problem got solved ! but one new problems came when i submit the form only get values of input fields not the star rating even star rating fields name not shown

Comment: solved! this.props was missing when I was implementing the onChange Method..... I love you guys to help me thank you Austin Greco you are real hero